# change text in single snackbar

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, snackbar

So, there are nth number of string value. One by one I need to display those string value on single snackbar after an interval. For example - "This is snackbar one" should get displayed for 1 min after that again "This is snackbar two" should get displayed.

Currently, I am getting all text in snackbar.Refer below image - [image]

HTML template -

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app light>
      <v-snackbar
        v-model="snackbar"
        :multi-line="mode === 'multi-line'"
        :timeout="timeout"
        :top="y === 'top'"
        :color="'success'"
        :messages.sync="messages"
      >
        <div>{{ text }}</div>
        <v-btn @click="snackbar = false"> X </v-btn>
      </v-snackbar>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      snackbar: true,
      y: "top",
      x: "right",
      mode: "",
      timeout: 6000,
      text: [
        "This is Snackbar ONE",
        "This is Snackbar TWO",
        "This is Snackbar THREE",
        "This is Snackbar FOUR",
        "This is Snackbar FIVE",
        "This is Snackbar SIX",
        "This is Snackbar SEVEN",
      ],
      indexText: 0,
      messages: [],
    };
  },

  async created() {
        showMessage() {
            console.log('this.text : ', this.text)
            if (this.indexText >= this.text.length) this.indexText = 0;
            this.messages.push(this.text[this.indexText++]);
            console.log('this.messages : ', this.messages)
       },
   },
};
</script>
```

Also adding SS for console.log -
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in your code, the `created` hook is asynchronous, so you cannot call the `showMessage` function inside the created hook. Instead, you should call the `showMessage` function inside the `mounted` hook.

Also, you need to set an interval to call the `showMessage` function after certain interval.

Here's the updated code, hope it helps:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app light>
      <v-snackbar
        v-model="snackbar"
        :multi-line="mode === 'multi-line'"
        :timeout="timeout"
        :top="y === 'top'"
        :color="'success'"
        :messages.sync="messages"
      >
        <div>{{ text }}</div>
        <v-btn @click="snackbar = false"> X </v-btn>
      </v-snackbar>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      snackbar: true,
      y: "top",
      x: "right",
      mode: "",
      timeout: 6000,
      text: [
        "This is Snackbar ONE",
        "This is Snackbar TWO",
        "This is Snackbar THREE",
        "This is Snackbar FOUR",
        "This is Snackbar FIVE",
        "This is Snackbar SIX",
        "This is Snackbar SEVEN",
      ],
      indexText: 0,
      messages: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showMessage() {
      if (this.indexText >= this.text.length) this.indexText = 0;
      this.messages.push(this.text[this.indexText++]);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.showMessage();
    }, 1000);
  },
};
</script>
```

In the above code, I have added a `mounted` hook and inside that, I have set an interval of 1 sec (1000 ms) which will call the `showMessage` function after every 1 sec.

Comment: I tried with that but first item is coming up then first and second both are coming then 1st,2nd and 3rd and so on after given time interval. Means its getting add on. I am trying that if 1st item comes up then after 1 sec 2nd item should appear and disappear the first one. Also, once all items get iterated the counter should again start from one